# jQuery - comparing value on each array

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I'm trying to compare the exact dates inside an array. I added a function that will compare the value into an array using `isInArray` function. Now I have a list of exact dates inside the array and tried to compare them. My only problem was I'm getting an error says *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined* on this code

```
if (isInArray(get_compare_date, get_all_dates_full)) {  
 ....
}
```

But when I tried to add a static array it is working good

```
if (isInArray(get_compare_date, ["November 9, 2017", "November 28, 2017"])) {   
 ....
}
```

This is what I've tried

```
    var data_arr = ['2017, 11, 09', '2017, 11, 26', '2017, 11, 29'];
    var get_all_dates_full = new Array;
    $.each(data_arr, function (key, value) {
        get_date_val = new Date(value);
        get_all_dates_full.push(get_date_val.format("mmmm d, yyyy"));
    });

    console.log(get_all_dates_full);

    function get_all_dates(){
    var now = new Date();
    $(".picker__day").each(function () {

        var get_compare_date = $(this).attr('aria-label');  

        //problem in if statement...
        if (isInArray(get_compare_date, get_all_dates_full)) {          
        console.log(get_compare_date);
            if (!$(this).hasClass("picker__day--disabled")) {
                $(this).addClass('picker__day--disabled');
                $(this).addClass('done-seminar');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('not-seminar');
            }
        }

    });
    }

    });

    //compare value into an array
    function isInArray(value, array) {
      return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
    }
```

Comment: which library you are using to format the date??

Comment: I'm using this one - http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: But you have not included the function where they are formatting the date. Anyways in which format you want the date?

Comment: Date Format needs to be in "mmmm d, yyyy" that is why I format them first and needs to compare into this var get_compare_date = $(this).attr('aria-label');  as the format was the same with "mmmm d, yyyy".

Comment: lol sorry.. I just mislook it. I did not include the date format into the function..Thank you @SanchitPatiyal!